# tags of struts-tags-json are unkonwn

Tags: struts2, struts2-json-plugin

Hi everyone  i have a problem when i use a struts-tags-json by a prefix "sj", so when i use the tag on the jsp page it tells me that the tag is unknown. For example  is unknown however i import the jar file <%@ taglib uri="/struts-json-tags" prefix="sj"%> 
for information i'm using myeclipce it configurs jars automaticly.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-json-tags" prefix="sj"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <sj:select> </sj:select>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding a `taglib` directive doesn't "import the jar file"; you still need the appropriate dependencies in your project.

Comment: Ok tell tell me please how to do that in myEclipse, I thought that it does that automaticly !

Comment: `/struts-json-tags` does not have `select` tag (it's in `/struts-tags`).